# Execute a jQuery function on a linked page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On my website I have a main page with different *overviews*. Then there are subpages with information about particular projects. The overviews are not shown by default (when the page is loaded), they must be triggered by a JavaScript function (usually by clicking a button).

However, I don't know how to link to an *overview* from a subpage. It's not enough to link to `href="/index"`, because the overview I want to link to still deserves to be revealed by JavaScript.

I have thought about making a clone page of my main page that shows the overview from the beginning. But this wouldn't be the right solution. I don't know much about PHP files, but might it be necessary for this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to take a look at one of the big frameworks (of course later on when you learnt the basic fundamentals of js), but for now try to href="/index/something" and on page load check if 'windows.location.search' contains the something, if yes show that overview.